# Composer.phar "Could not rename /tmp..."

Tags: symfony, composer-php, phar

I want to install FOSUserBundle I added to composer.json   `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*"` I executed this command `php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` And I get message

```
 Could not rename "tmp/cmpec7db/FriendsOfSymfony-FOSUserBundle-5a4db1f/Command" 
 to /home/pathtopublic_html/public_html/acme/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
 /FOS/UserBudnle/Command
```

But where I find temp folder? I can't see any tmp folder on web server I try add fos in webserver. I use Symfony 2.1.x and Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a local tmp directory in your project folder.
[here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1765) is the solution.